# directive reacting to attribute change

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive, with an attribute :

html :

```
<my-directive id="test" myattr="50"></my-directive>
```

js :

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {

    var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch('myattr', function(value) {
            element.attr('myattr', value);
        });

        scope.change = function() {
            // some code
        };
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-change="change()" ng-model="myattr"/>',
        scope: {myattr: '='},
        link: link
    };
});
```

My goal would be to keep `myattr` and the value of the input equal. With `element.attr('myattr', value)` I can force `myattr` to have the correct value, but how am I supposed to update the input when `myattr` changes?

For example, in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7ujcjb8/2/), when clicking on the button, I try to do :

```
$('#test').attr('myattr', Math.random() * 100);
```

But I can't find a way to 'catch' the change from within the directive.

I would like some help modifying the jsfiddle so that :

1. the function `change` is called after the jquery call.
2. the value of the input is always equal to `myattr`

Comment: what you're missing is triggering the event listener that angular listens to once the input is updated ; [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/d7ujcjb8/28/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value of myattr as a property on a scope not as a value on an attribute.

Your directive is correct you need to also attach a controller.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.calculate = function () {
    // your logic here
    alert($scope.val);
  }
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {

  var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    
    scope.change = function() {
      console.log("change " + scope.myattr);
    };

  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-change="change()" ng-model="myattr"/>',
    scope: {
      myattr: '='
    },
    link: link
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    My Value: {{val}} <br/>

    <button type="button" ng-click="calculate()">ok</button>
    <my-directive id="test" myattr="val"></my-directive>    
  </div>


</div>
```